# Slickgrid - Background Polling to keep data up-to-date?

Tags: ajax, slickgrid

I have a small Django-based webapp used to assigning people to various accomodation rooms, workshops, lectures etc.

I'm hoping to use Slickgrid to present an editable grid for people to edit values with. There will be multiple people (around 5-10 to begin with) who will be hitting the same table with writes. In theory, they should be touching different parts of the table, but there will be some overlap (e.g. how many spare slots there are in a given room).

I'm wondering what mechanisms there are that I can use with Slickgrid in order to ensure that they are all viewing (relatively) up-to-date data?

Is there some kind of background polling that can be done? Or can an edit by one user trigger a refresh on everybody else's session? Or is something like that not really feasible across the web?

If Slickgrid isn't suitable for this, what other web-based data-tables are available that would handle heavy concurrent edits?

(I know Google Wave does cool things with operational transforms, I'm hoping for something a bit simpler/dumber...lol)

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not record the last update time for the grid, then AJAX poll to see the time of the last update on your data, then update the grid's data object as necessary?